# How can I get the user whom changed a file with a watchman trigger?

Tags: git, watchman

When using the [watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/) trigger functionality does anyone know how to get the name of the user responsible for the trigger?

What I am trying to do, is to version data files automatically to a local git. For this I am watching a folder and executing a trigger whenever a file is changed (added, deleted or modified). This triggers a script which then performs a git add and git commit.

What I did:

```
watchman watch /data
watchman -- trigger /data git-commit '*' -- sh git_commit.sh
```

However that performs all commits in my name instead of the user who performed the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, this cannot be done in watchman directly. The plan now is to use [auditctl](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl) for this.